# Foreground app activity over 100%?

Tags: ios, instruments, xcode-instruments

I was just monitoring my iOS game's energy usage and I see that the foreground app activity often goes as high as 126%.  I am just wondering if this is something I should be concerned about?  The energy usage shows a constant value of 1/20--- yet the time column is always "00:00 - 00:00", so I am a little confused about what that means.

Also, is there a way to disable bluetooth, gps in my app since those features are unused?  I assume they would contribute to some sort of energy usage. Instruments shows no information other than state is "on" with a time of "00:00".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html

> The Energy Usage instrument indicates a level from 0 to 20, indicating
>   how much energy your app is using at any given time. These numbers are
>   subjective. If your app’s energy usage level is occasionally high, it
>   doesn’t necessarily mean that your app has a problem. Your app may
>   simply require more energy for some of the tasks it performs. For
>   example, it may use the GPS while performing complex network
>   operations. This is valid energy use. What you should look for are
>   spikes or areas of high energy use that are unexpected or that could
>   be performed at more optimal times.

I don't think I'd sweat what you are seeing too much. What is your FPS? Are you maintaining a 60 fps? Your main time is spent on your foreground app, so if you're looking to thin it down you should looking at what your CPU is doing. You an look at Time Profiler if you want to see if you can improve performance there.

That being said, I think users do realize battery life will suffer if you're playing a game. However, that comment should be tempered with the type of game. If you're doing Tic Tac Toe and you're sucking the life out of a battery, I think you'll raise some brows.

You don't have means (which won't get you rejected) to forcibly turn off things. And even if you could you also could end up with angry users too. Say you're using a bluetooth headset ... and you kill bluetooth?

Just make sure your game is fun and people will forgive you ;)